# Adding an app to iOS simulator to access from Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, ios-simulator

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that needs to launch a second app (TeamViewer). In order to test this, I need to add TeamViewer to the simulator that XF attaches to. The simulator runs on my Mac. Is there a way to get TeamViewer onto the simulator so that my app can launch it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you delete your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75328325/6309)? I wanted to know if my process did help you.

Comment: I didn't delete it.A moderator did as a duplicate.

Comment: Strange. I see on that post: " It was deleted yesterday by the post author. "